# How to use my classes from Scala worksheet in IntelliJ CE with Scala plugin?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I can not use my classes from Scala worksheet in IntelliJ CE with Scala plugin.

I do the following:

1. Create Scala SBT project.
2. In src/main/scala create package `test1`.
3. In this package create class

> ```
> package test1
> class TestClass {
> }
> ```

4. In the same package create Scala worksheet ws1.sc, inside it create object `ws1`, inside it put a couple of expressions. It works.

[image: Screenshot 1]

5. When I add `new ScalaTest` to object `ws1`, IntelliJ adds `import test1.ScalaTest`, but evaluation of worksheet does not work.

[image: Screenshot 2]

If I add `package test1` to my worksheet, it does not work at all, with warning "Package name doesn't correspond to directories structure, this may cause problem with resolve to classes from the file"

[image: Screenshot 3]

Is there any ideas how to use my classes from worksheet?

Comment: AFAIK, classes defined inside Scala worksheets cannot be referenced from outside the worksheet. Worksheets are for quick, throwaway testing only. Why don't you create regular Scala classes and objects?

Comment: Nope, ScalaTest is regular class, it is defined outside worksheet, look at screenshot.

Comment: How exactly does evaluation of the worksheet fail in step 5? - I see no problems there.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **eclipse compatibility** mode:

> Settings → Languages & Frameworks → Scala → Worksheet → use "eclipse compatibility" mode

Answer (score 4):

You must tick "Make project" next to the "Interactive mode"